# Possible to Reinstall Bento

Tags: install, license, bento

I recently had to wipe clean my harddrive. I had a Bento DB installed and so I had to reinstall it. I have the original license key, however, since FileMaker no longer supports Bento it isn't working. Any ideas on how I might be able to open my database?

Comment: How did you access your Bento DB *before* the wipe? Can you get the application you used back from your backup?

Answer (score 1):

Check the "archived software downloads"-section on their homepage [here](http://www.filemaker.com/support/downloads/downloads_prev_versions.html). There is a section for Bento v1, 2, 3 or 4, your product should be included as well. For example, try downloading Bento v4.1.2 from [here](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11182) ;)